# Whats the differences between .net Core Installer (RC2) and .Net Core SDK Installer (Preview 1)?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

.Net Core RC2 is now available as of an hour or so ago as indicated here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/05/16/announcing-updated-web-development-tools-for-asp-net-core-rc2/

Downloads are available at https://www.microsoft.com/net/download but it's not clear what the differences is between the ".net Core Installer (RC2)" and the ".Net Core SDK Installer (Preview 1)?"

I'm assuming that the ".Net Core SDK Installer (Preview 1)" contains everything that "net Core Installer (RC2)" does, but it's not clear.

Anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

".NET Core" is a runtime only, while ".NET Core SDK" is a runtime (same one) and additional tools.

For your developer machine you need ".NET Core SDK".

Comment: Dmitry - thanks, that's was my hunch but I wasn't sure.  Can you cite a source or provide a reference?

Comment: Download `NET Core binaries only` and `NET Core SDK binaries only` zips and compare contents :)